# How can I change the position of the mouse cursor in OpenGL/SFML?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, multiplatform

I'm writing a simple FPS game and I'm going to have the mouse control the camera.
I'm using SFML library for C++.
How can i set mouse position to the center of the window.
Can you help me to find multiplatform version of the setCursorPos (Windows only)

// Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- `sf::Window::SetCursorPosition` for SFML 1.6
- `sf::Mouse::SetPosition` for SFML 2.0

Comment: Thank you! Why I couldn't find it in the docs (oO)
Sorry, I can't vote up until I have 15 points(((

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to set the mouse position http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Window.php#a369d1764893c6fde8979fcf04142dc55 in sfml.